# jQuery/Javascript Detect when user wants to scroll further -the "bounce" effect at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website with 8 different sections. For the mobile version, I want that once the user has reached the bottom of a section if he tries to scroll further down, right after (or instead of) the content bounce that usually happens, the next section will come up.

I already know how to detect when the user reaches the bottom using jquery

```
function check_bottom(e)
{
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight())
    {}
}
```

but how do I know if he tries to scroll past that point?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think the bounce effect is browser (maybe even operating system) specific.  Chrome + Mac: I get the bounce but IE + Windows: I don't get a bounce.

Comment: Hi Doug! ...the bounce effect is just to exemplify when I want it to happen. In general terms, I want that if the user scrolled a div all the way to the bottom, if he tries to scroll again it will bring the next section up. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you can detect past the dimensions of a page -- what if you added some padding/margin at the bottom and set the condition that detects the bottom offset by the bottom padding?